# Accesing and removing session that was set with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, session, model-view-controller

I've got on my web application several session variables that were set using ajax's  `sessionStorage.setItem`

[image: session variables]

e.g
 `sessionStorage.setItem("id", 345 );`

***What I need to do is*** to access,change and most importantly remove such variables from my c# Controller

**What I've tried so far for removing/destroying session variables**

```
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Remove("id")
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
```

**What I've tried so far for accessing session variables**

```
 var sesionId = {Controller}.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["{id}"];
 var sesionId = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["{id}"];
 var sesionId = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["{id}"];
 //all return null
```

These failed trials were taken from other similar questions here in Stackoverflow but I believe the method in which the variables were set may have something to do with the fact those methods are not working out for me.

Comment: Seems that you are confusing client-side javascript `window.sessionStorage` and server-side `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` - please, clarify.

Comment: Igor I've also tried using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["id"];` with no sucess. These session variables were originally gotten from the database and were set using  javascript's `sessionStorage.setItem` but now I need to modify and remove those variables from another c# controller

Comment: The two containers are completely different and unrelated - one is in the browser, the other is on the server.

Comment: Ok then, I was not aware of the differences and thought was trying to access the same thing. So it isn't possible to access a session variable created in javascript from a c# controller or is it?

Comment: Of course, it is possible to remove items from javascript `sessionsStorage` - but only by executing javascript code that you include in the page and then call client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Igor mentioned I was having a theory related error and I quote

> The two containers are completely different and unrelated - one is in the browser, the other is on the server.
>
> Seems that you are confusing client-side javascript window.sessionStorage and server-side System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

Issue was resolved due to his sharp observation